# How to find and fix rows in MySQL that contain characters that aren't letters in any language's alphabet?

Tags: php, mysql, internationalization, character, collation

I inherited a large database of cities around the world.

I noticed that some cities have garbled names in the `placeName` column.

For example:

`Cité Administrative de l'Etat` appears as `CitÃ© Administrative de l'Etat` in the database.

The collation of the `placeName` column is `utf8_general_ci` and the collation of the table is `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`.

How can I find all the cities names in column `placeName` that do not contain letters that belong to any language's alphabet?

Once those are found, how can I automatically fix them so that, for example, `CitÃ© Administrative de l'Etat` becomes `Cité Administrative de l'Etat` without having to do each one manually one by one?

Comment: Don't you have a way to re-INSERT these values in your DB? Because you'll have the same problem with éèàù ... It would be easier to set the correct encoding on your PHP script and then INSERT the values or update them.

Comment: You could try `INSERT ... SELECT CONVERT( ... USING utf8)` : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html - because *"CitÃ©"* looks very much like what happens when you try and stuff UTF data into 8859-1 (UTF-8 has twice as many bits per character as Latin, so you get 2 incorrect characters for anything beyond ASCII) - get that sorted then you'll probably want to go through *the checklist* : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through/279279

Comment: @JulienLachal I do not have the original data, so I'm stuck with the garbled data currently in the DB and that's all I have to work with unfortunately.

Comment: @CD001 Would the `CONVERT` function fix and convert `CitÃ© Administrative de l'Etat` to `Cité Administrative de l'Etat` ?

Comment: Should do - I've had to do it a few times on old databases I've inherited; try just doing it as a `SELECT` initially to check, you could export that to a CSV then verify the data in say OpenOffice Calc to be on the safe side.

Comment: @CD001 Unfortunately, it did not work:  http://i.imgur.com/EZYYx06.png   Any other ideas?

Comment: Try this: `SELECT CONVERT(CAST(CONVERT(\`placeName\` USING latin1) AS BINARY) USING utf8) AS placeName FROM \`YOUR_TABLE\`` ... I actually put something like that (along with some other stuff) into a MySQL Function so I wouldn't have to remember it ;)

Comment: @CD001 That worked!  Thanks so much.  Please add it as a solution so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Look for Mojibake in [Trouble with utf8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) to see what went wrong.

Then http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#fixes_for_various_cases to see how to repair the tables.